# Unable to show parent together with count of children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Class named Question and a related Class named Answers. I want to return the Question in JSON format, together with the grouped count of the Answers. As an example:

```
["question":"What's 3 x 4?", ["12":15, "10":2]]
```

So 15 respondents have said it's 12 and 2 have said it's 10.

Now, I can return the array from the Answers, using the following code:

```
@answers = Answer.where(:question_id => params[:id]).count(:group => 'answer')
```

I can also add the Answers for each user, using the following code:

```
format.json { render json: @question , :include => :answers, :conditions => {:answers => { :user_id => user_id}}}
```

But I am unable to return both the Question, together with the counted, grouped by array of results...

Please advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jbuilder gem](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) for building your own json-templates.

```
# /app/views/question.show.json.jbuilder
if question
  json.id question.id
  json.answers do |answer|
    json.answer_text answer.text
    json.answer_count answer.count
  end
else 
  nil
end
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I will dive into this gem. Sounds like a good approach.